# Exclude display:none div from nth child count

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a List Group made in Bootstrap 4

HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.list-group-item:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 0.8rem;
 border-top-right-radius: 0.8rem;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0.8rem;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0.8rem;
}
```

I have a simple script that adds or remove the 'd-none' class to elements of this list, the problem is that the border radius CSS of the List Group counts also the elements with the d-none class.

This way the bottom corners are never rounded by the CSS, because it takes into consideration even the subsequent childs with display:none attribute.

[image: Line 3 and 4 are hidden with .d-none]

Line 3 and 4 are hidden with .d-none. I need the bottom corners of line 2 rounded by the CSS as it the last visible child.

Is there a way to temporarily remove the nodes with javascript so that they're not counted in CSS?

Comment: why not put the radius on the parent, and hide the overflow ?

Comment: There is something else is happening your code works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qks7tvdz/

Comment: The parent still counts the hidden elements, so it appears longer than it is if I highlight it in the ispector. the radius it's applied to the single element by bootstrap CSS.

Comment: @vanowm Hide the top and bottom child and you will see the issue

Comment: @charlietfl now I understand. I guess without involving javascript your only option is to round corners of the parent element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be use classes for the radius instead and whenever you make a change to display of items in the list reset the classes on first and last visible element in the list

```js
const $list = $('.list-group');


function toggleFirstLast($list){
   const $items = $list.children().removeClass('first-visible last-visible')
   
   $items.filter(':visible:first').addClass('first-visible');
   $items.filter(':visible:last').addClass('last-visible')

}


toggleFirstLast($list)
```

```css
.list-group-item {border:2px solid green; list-style-type:none}

.list-group-item.first-visible {
 border-top-left-radius: 0.8rem;
 border-top-right-radius: 0.8rem;
}

.list-group-item.last-visible {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0.8rem;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item first-visible" style="display:none">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"  style="display:none">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" style="display:none">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item last-visible">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```